# Laravel : raw sql subquery

Tags: mysql, laravel, subquery

I know Raw statements could create **SQL injection vulnerabilities** , 
but i want to copy paste the subqueries from my terminal to laravel controller cause really i'm out of time and i need to hurry.

i want something like this :

```
$nmbrP = DB::select('SELECT count(*) from ( SELECT patient , medcine from dossier_medicals GROUP by patient having medcine = ? ) as nbr;' , [$id]);
dd($nmbrP);
```

the subquery is working perfectly working in the **terminal** but throwing an error in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$nmbrP = DB::selectRaw('count(*) from ( SELECT patient , medcine from 
dossier_medicals GROUP by patient having medcine = ? ) as nbr;' , [$id]);
dd($nmbrP);
```

more about selectRaw in:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#raw-methods